# SalesforceIQ: Getting all Contact objects

Tags: contact, salesforceiq

I'm trying to use the API docs for SalesforceIQ (here: https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/python) to retrieve all of my Contact objects.  As is, I'm only getting the first 200.  I'm doing this:

```
def get_all_contacts():
    contacts = Contact().fetchPage()
    return contacts
```

I want to get ALL of the Contact objects, though.  How would I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to Adrian's answer, you need to run a loop until you there're no more records left to be retrieved in batches of 200. Something along these lines (check the exact syntax based on Python version/ framework you use)

```
def get_all_contacts():
    startIndex = 0
    limit = 200
    allContacts = Contact().fetchPage(startIndex,limit)
    moreContacts = allContacts
    while moreContacts is not None
        startIndex + = limit
        moreContacts = Contact().fetchPage(startIndex,limit)
    allContacts.append(moreContacts)
    return allContacts
```

Comment: Should it be moreContacts += Contact().fetchPage(startIndex, limit)

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you link, the optional `_limit` parameter has a maximum value of 200 when getting all records from a list.

> **Get All List Items**
>
> `_limit`
>   **[Numeric]**
>   An optional page size for the returned result (defaults to 50, max size is 200).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How would you recommend I go about getting all Contact objects then?  Is there a way to get the "2nd" batch of 200?   Thanks for the help!